# How to set Priority on UIScrollview and Animation

Tags: ios, iphone, animation, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

On each page there is a view(instance of UIView) in which i have some animation.

When I scroll page from page1 to page2,animation in page2 occurs and it works fine but again when I scroll from page2 to page1, it gets stuck for some time. As ScrollView and Animation are on main thread.

Is there any way to set priority for Scrollview, so that scroll occurs first !!

i.e if animation is working and I scroll to another page then page should change smoothly,it should not wait for completion of my animation.

Have searched over web But still did not find any Solution. Please help!
Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please check by adding this just after the completion of you animation.

```
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

---

You need to commit your animation every time once you start it.

Thanks.